# Decrypt AES 256 CBC

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption

I have a function in PHP that decrypts my MP3 files, this function works perfectly, but when I translated it into VB.NET, I didn't get the same result.

The key, the IV and the ciphertext are generated normally and match what is generated by PHP, but the plaintext has different results.

This is my code in PHP

```php
HIDDEN
```

and this is my code in VB.net that I translated

```vb
HIDDEN
```

This is a part of the first result in PHP

```
fff320c4000818361800798209025d
```

and this is part of the result I'm getting from my code

```
E39457922BB49015E76133D391D6CFB9C5
```

this is my new code in VB.Net after Topaco's suggestions

```
HIDDEN
```

What are the returns: the Key, IV and Cyphertext in both cases (PHP and VB.Net) are correct and equal, except for the last block of the Cyphertext which has 16 bits more (zeros at the end of the block)

Another problem is that with PKCS7, I get the Error: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

Comment: There are bugs in your PHP code. You create a key of 128 bits and then specify AES-256 to be used. I think that means that the key is 16 bytes that you take from the hash, and then 16 bytes set to zero. You'll have to create the same key size manually for VB, just setting the key size of the cipher won't get you there. In both cases you make the mistake to use the first 16 bytes of the ciphertext as IV instead of the last one, and you've forgotten about what padding will do.

Comment: I'd strongly always using an output stream for creating ciphertext and an inputstream for reading ciphertext. Of course you don't need the memory stream - [or the buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-7.0) in that case. After you fix the padding thingy of course.

Comment: In addition to the too short key: Use `PaddingMode.PKCS7` in the C# code. And regarding the last ciphertext chunk: This is generally smaller than `ciphertext.Length` (the actual length is returned by `Read()`). In `Write()` the actual length must be specified. With these changes decryption with the C# code works.

Comment: One drawback of your encryption logic is that the chunk size must be known during decryption. This is because the individual chunks but not the entire ciphertext is CBC compliant. For the latter, disable padding for all chunks except the last one, and use the last (instead of the first) block of a chunk as IV for the following chunk. Then any chunk size (equal to a multiple of the block size) can be used for decryption.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes thanks for your help, and sorry for the delay in responding, I was working on other processes and couldn't follow up on this one...... As for what you asked... yes, there are 16 bytes removed from the hash, but no has another 16 bytes defined as zeros. How can I know if the key contains 16 bytes defined as zeros? in PHP I converted the key into a byte array, and I did the same thing in VB.net, the two keys are the same, with the same size and format

Comment: @Topaco thanks also for your help, I did what you suggested and switched to Read() mode, and the length worked, but when I put PaddingMode.PKCS7, this error is generated: the fill is invalid and cannot be removed, how can I resolve this?
As for your second comment, I didn't quite understand that part "For the latter, disable padding for all chunks except the last one, and use the last (instead of the first) block of a chunk as IV for the following chunk. Then any chunk size (equal to a multiple of the block size) can be used for decryption." Do you have any example of how I can do it?

Comment: Regarding the 1st part: Edit your question and attach your most recent VB code with your changes at the end (please do not overwrite the old VB code for future readers).

Comment: Regarding the 2nd part: This is a suggestion to change the encryption so that the decryption becomes independent of the chunk size. For PHP the encryption part is discussed e.g. in [this post and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77480273/9014097). Start with the encryption, then implement the corresponding decryption. Finally, both can be ported to VB (if desired). If you have problems, please post a new question (as this is clearly beyond the scope of this question).

Comment: @Topaco, I just edited my question

Comment: Well, I don't really know why my suggested change should lead to such a big code change. Anyway, try this code: https://pastebin.com/k7Kc8sqS. If I remember correctly, I was able to successfully perform the decryption with this at the time.

Comment: @Topaco, it worked perfectly.... Thank you very much.... From what I saw, the biggest problem was in the key, which is actually 32 and was only passing 16...... I converted some mp3 files that I have here, and they all worked perfectly..... How can I mark it as an answer?

Comment: There are *several* bugs, each of which generally (but not necessarily always) either results in an exception during decryption or corrupts the data. I have described this in more detail in my answer. Additionally, I suggested a change regarding the *single* `Read()` call (although the old code should work most of the time, this is not *guaranteed*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following bugs in the VB code:

- PHP/OpenSSL uses PKCS#7 padding by default. However, padding is disabled in the current VB code, which is why the padding bytes of the chunks are not removed. Therefore, padding must be enabled in the VB code (either by explicitly specifying PKCS#7 padding, or by removing the explicit padding specification so that the default padding, which is PKCS#7, is used). The fix is labeled *Fix 1* in the code.
- When reading the ciphertext data, the current code assumes that a [`Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=net-8.0) call fills the entire buffer. However, this is not guaranteed (s. [*Returns*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=net-8.0) section), so that too little data can be read into the buffer. Therefore, the implementation must be stabilized in such a way that `Read()` is called in a loop until the buffer is completely filled or the end of the file is reached. The number of data read into the buffer after exiting the loop is stored (`numBytesRead`). The fix is labeled *Fix 2a* in the code.
  In addition, the current code always reads the entire buffer when writing the data. Even if it is assumed that the buffer would be completely filled by a `Read()` call, the last chunk is generally always smaller than the buffer size, so that too much data would be written when reading out the entire buffer. Therefore, the implementation must be stabilized so that only as much data is read from the buffer as was read in (`numBytesRead`). The fix is labeled *Fix 2b* in the code.
- In the PHP code, AES-256 is used in conjunction with a 16 bytes key that is too short. PHP/OpenSSL silently generates a 32 bytes key from this invalid 16 bytes key by padding with 0x00 values. This does not happen automatically in the VB code and must be implemented explicitly. The fix is labeled *Fix 3* in the code.

Full code:

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

...

Dim path_source As String = "C:\Teste\61.mp3.enc"
Dim path_dest As String = "C:\Teste\61.mp3"

Dim cryptKey As String = "0d8pkTOROILJBjV1gqxUpSc-Pk67l2Sw2qmooJaGujJ9_iiQ=" 'exemple my cryptkey
Dim key As Byte() = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cryptKey)).Take(16).ToArray()
key = key.Concat(New Byte(32 - key.Length() - 1) {}).ToArray()  ' Fix 3


Using fpOut As FileStream = New FileStream(path_dest, FileMode.Create)
    Using fpIn As FileStream = New FileStream(path_source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim iv As Byte() = New Byte(15) {}
        fpIn.Read(iv, 0, 16)

        Dim plaintext As Byte()
        While fpIn.Position < fpIn.Length
            Dim numBytesRead As Integer = 0
            Dim numBytesToRead As Integer = 160016
            Dim ciphertext As Byte() = New Byte(numBytesToRead - 1) {}
            While (numBytesToRead > 0)
                Dim n As Integer = fpIn.Read(ciphertext, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead) ' Fix 2a
                If (n = 0) Then
                    Exit While
                End If
                numBytesRead = (numBytesRead + n)
                numBytesToRead = (numBytesToRead - n)
            End While

            Try
                Using AES As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()

                    AES.BlockSize = 128
                    AES.KeySize = 256
                    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 ' Fix 1
                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
                    AES.Key = key
                    AES.IV = iv
                    Console.WriteLine("AES IV:          " & BitConverter.ToString(AES.IV))
                    Dim decipher As ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateDecryptor(AES.Key, AES.IV)
                    Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                        Using cs As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(ms, decipher, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                            cs.Write(ciphertext, 0, numBytesRead) ' Fix 2b
                            cs.FlushFinalBlock()
                        End Using
                        plaintext = ms.ToArray()
                    End Using
                End Using
                iv = ciphertext.Take(16).ToArray()
                fpOut.Write(plaintext, 0, plaintext.Length)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message)
            End Try
        End While
        Console.WriteLine("end of file")
    End Using
End Using
```

With these changes, an (mp3) file encrypted with PHP/OpenSSL can be successfully decrypted with the VB code on my machine.

---

The current PHP code encrypts each chunk with PKCS#7 padding in CBC mode, using the first ciphertext block of the previous chunk as the IV for the encryption of a chunk (in the case of the first chunk, the actual IV is used). This means that although each individual encrypted chunk is CBC compliant, the concatenation of the encrypted chunks is not (in other words, encrypting the entire plaintext at once provides a different ciphertext). This logic has the clear disadvantage that the chunk size must be known for decryption, so that each encrypted chunk can be identified and decrypted.

To get rid of this disadvantage, the following changes are necessary:

- Disable PKCS#7 padding for all chunks except the last chunk.
- The last (not the first!) ciphertext block of the previous chunk is to be used as the IV for the encryption of a chunk (in the case of the first chunk, the actual IV is used as before).

With this change, decryption can be implemented in such a way that it is independent of the chunk size used for encryption.

In [this post and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77480273/9014097) you will find information on how to modify your PHP code accordingly. If you have further questions about this approach, you should ask a new question, as this goes beyond the scope of the old question.

---

Security: Your logic has some vulnerabilities. Using a fast digest like SHA-1 for a key derivation function is bad. Instead, a reliable key derivation function such as Argon2 or at least PBKDF2 should be applied.
In addition, a 32 bytes key should be used for AES-256 in which each individual byte is determined randomly from a value range between 0 and 255 and none in which the last 16 bytes consist of 0x00 values. This ultimately reduces security from 256 bits to 128 bits.