# replicate openssl encrypt/decrypt between PHP and Command Line for large files?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, large-files, php-openssl

I am trying to create a PHP method to replicate the OpenSSL command line function so I can encrypt using the command line and then decrypt it using PHP or the opposite by encrypting using PHP and then decrypting using the command line.

i created this PHP method for encrypting files:

```
$salt= random_bytes(8);
$saltPrefix = "Salted__" . $salt;
$keyIV= EVP_BytesToKey($salt, file_get_contents('my.key'));
$key = substr($keyIV, 0, 32);
$original = file_get_contents('confidential.txt');
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($original, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
file_put_contents('php-encrypted.bin', $saltPrefix . $encrypted);
```

then after running this method, I can decrypt it using this command line:

```
openssl  enc -p -d -aes-256-cbc -in php-encrypted.bin -out decrypted.txt -pass file:my.key
```

but there is a problem when the file to encrypt is large so I try to update the above PHP method to don't get memory limit issue:

```
$FILE_ENCRYPTION_BLOCKS = 64;
if ($fpOut = fopen('php-encrypted.bin', 'w')) {
    fwrite($fpOut, $saltPrefix);
    if ($fpIn = fopen('confidential.txt', 'rb')) {
        while (!feof($fpIn)) {
            $plaintext = fread($fpIn, 16 * $FILE_ENCRYPTION_BLOCKS);
            $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
            fwrite($fpOut, $encrypted);
        }
        fclose($fpIn);
    }
    fclose($fpOut);
}
```

but when i try to decrypt the generated file as before using the command line it is not working. i need to update the above method to follow memory performance issue but want to keep it able to be encrypted using command line like the original method.

Comment: If you want to perform an AES/CBC encryption *successively* in chunks (which correspond to an integer multiple of one block or 16 bytes), for the encryption of a *plaintext* chunk the *last* block of the *previous ciphertext* chunk must be used as IV (for the first plaintext chunk, the *actual* IV is applied), see also the [CBC flow chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)). In addition, padding must be disabled for all chunks (with the exception of the last one). Similar applies to decryption.

Comment: i try replace `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA ` by this `$options = feof($fpIn) ? OPENSSL_RAW_DATA : OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING; ` and inside the loop, at the end, i add `$iv = substr($encrypted, 0, 16);` but still the decryption command line not working.

Comment: You have to use the *last* block of the previous ciphertext chunk as IV, not the first one: `$iv = substr($encrypted, -16);`

Comment: ah sorry for that i thinks first block, very thanks @Topaco it is working now.

Comment: if I want to use **CTR** what changes to be done for openssl_encrypt to encrypt chunks where I can send the counter and how to get it?

Comment: Take a look at the flow chart for CTR. Also, this is a new question.

Comment: sure, I checked CTR and created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77486403/create-php-code-for-large-files-openssl-encrypt-using-aes-256-ctr-compatible-wit) for this. thanks.